# tempt to perform arithmetic on a vector3 value fivem

Tags: lua, fivem

In F8 console I get error : attempt to perform arithmetic on a vector3 value.
And any marker and menu can pop. This error create some beug and the script doesn't work :(

````
local coords      = GetEntityCoords(PlayerPedId())
local isInMarker  = false
local currentZone = nil
for k,v in pairs(Config.Zones) do
            if(#(coords - v.Pos) < v.Size.x) then
                isInMarker  = true
                currentZone = k
            end
        end```
````

Comment: are you sure v.Pos is a vector3 or number?

Comment: v.pos = `DMVSchool = {
  Pos   = {x = 239.471, y = -1380.960, z = 32.741},
  Size  = {x = 1.5, y = 1.5, z = 1.0},
  Color = {r = 204, g = 204, b = 0},
  Type  = 1
 }`

Answer (score 0):

If this is one of the zones you're iterating over:

> DMVSchool = {         Pos   = {x = 239.471, y = -1380.960, z = 32.741},
> Size  = {x = 1.5, y = 1.5, z = 1.0},        Color = {r = 204, g = 204, b
> = 0},         Type  = 1   }

v.Pos is a standard Lua table value, not a vector3.

You cannot do arrithmetics between a vector3 and a table.

You probably need to initialize field 'Pos' as `Pos   = vector3(239.471,-1380.960,32.741)`.

See https://docs.fivem.net/docs/scripting-reference/runtimes/lua/functions/vector3/